# Keystone JS (generator-keystone) npm install fails

Tags: keystonejs

I have installed `Keystone` with `Yeoman Generator`.
`yo keystone` command runs without errors, but the following `npm install` finishes with error:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...6.4","react":"^16.8.6'
```

Data from debug log

```
2317 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...6.4","react":"^16.8.6'
2317 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2317 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
2317 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
2317 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Is your package.json correctly formatted?

Comment: @QuinnKeaveney I have not made any changes to `package.json` after `yo keystone`